# Photons moving relative to photons

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I know we can't move at the speed of light, but if we were to travel on a photon how fast would we see other photons going? The speed of light is constant... So do photons see other photons moving at the speed of light?

Comment: I know there are no giraffes on the moon, but if there were giraffes on the moon, what would their names be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Special Relativity, an object moving with speed *c* in one frame of reference moves with speed *c* in *all* frames of reference.

The immediate consequence is this:  *a photon has no frame of reference*.

To appreciate this fully, consider that, no matter what speed you travel with respect to something else, *you are at rest with respect to yourself*.

But, and again, according to SR, if you were to have speed *c* in any frame of reference, *there would be no frame of reference in which you were at rest with respect to yourself*.

The bottom line is that asking a question along the lines of your question presumes that there exists a frame of reference that moves with speed *c* in which observations can be made.

But, *there isn't*!

Answer (score 2):

The frame of reference of something moving at the speed of light is not well-defined within special relativity. A photon does not see anything, it just is. For a mathematical argument, look at the relativistic factor $\gamma$, which appears in relativistic equations:

$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{v}{c})^2}}.$$

If you set $v$ equal to $c$, this expression is equivalent to a division by zero.